# Python - I can only save one thing with append?

Tags: python, list, save, append

Here is my code. I can't save more than 1 thing in the list, I don't know why.

The point of the program is to save words (like "banana") and then add a description to it ("yellow"). I'm using Python 2.7

```
word = []  
desc = []

def main_list():

    print "\nMenu for list \n"
    print "1: Insert"
    print "2: Lookup"
    print "3: Exit program"

    choice = input()
    print "Choose alternative: ", choice

    if choice == 1:
        insert()
    elif choice == 2:
        look()
    elif choice == 3:
        return
    else:
        print "Error: not a valid choice"

def insert():
    word.append(raw_input("Word to insert: "))
    desc.append(raw_input ("Description of word: "))
    main_list()

def look():
    up = raw_input("Word to lookup: ")
    i = 0
    while up != word[i]:
        i+1
    print "Description of word: ", desc[i]
    main_list()
```

Comment: What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: How do you run this? There's no main method that calls those.

Comment: Everything works fine if I only insert the word "banana" and the description "yellow" but if I also add something else, like "computer" with a description then I can only  look() at the "banana". If i look() with "computer" nothing happends, the program just seems to load forever. Do you think Python 2.7 might be a problem?

Comment: @Kaiser provide full code and sample input data and the problem you are facing in the question

Comment: Just run main_list() and then follow the texted instructions, press 1-3 to pick a choice.

Comment: In your code try `i += 1` instead of just `i+1`. No assignment happens so the look just keeps checking the same place in the list.

Comment: @Kaiser why are you using recursive calls there is no need for that

Comment: I'm both new and pretty bad with programming

Comment: As Vignesh says, there's no need for recursion here. So you should get rid of those calls to `main_list()` in `insert()` and `look()`, and put the code in  `main_list()` inside a `while True:` loop. You could then replace the `return` under `choice == 3` with `break`, although that's not totally necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not updating the value of `i`. You're calling `i+1` which doesn't really do anything (it simply evaluates `i + 1` and discards the result). Do instead `i += 1` which seems to work.

Furthermore that's a rather strange approach to creating a dictionary, when you have a built-in data structure for that - the dictionary (`{}`).

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: You can accept my answer and be rewarded with 2 rep points as a result!

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not use two list to save the words and their respective descriptions.

This is a classic case for using a dictionary, which will also help you once you have a lot of words, as you do not need to loop over all entries to find the corresponding description.

```
words = {}

def main_list():

    print "\nMenu for list \n"
    print "1: Insert"
    print "2: Lookup"
    print "3: Exit program"

    choice = input()
    print "Choose alternative: ", choice

    if choice == 1:
        insert()
    elif choice == 2:
        look()
    elif choice == 3:
        return
    else:
        print "Error: not a valid choice"

def insert():
    word = raw_input("Word to insert: ")
    desc = raw_input ("Description of word: ")
    words[word] = desc
    main_list()

def look():
    up = raw_input("Word to lookup: ")
    print "Description of word: ", words.get(up, "Error: Word not found")
    main_list()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will try it out now.